# Simplify a regex - multiple discrete options

Tags: regex

```
^(\d{2}|\d{4}|\d{6}|\d{8})N
```

Basically, is there any way to do the above shorter/simpler? Is there a way to express multiple discrete digit counts within those curly brackets, rather than a single continuous range?

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:\d{2}){1,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/DbmIHS/1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to match even number of digits *n* times.

You may group the `\d{2}` subpattern and apply a limiting quantifier to it:

```
^(?:\d{2}){1,4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbmIHS/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{2}){1,4}` - 1 to 4 (`4` can be adjusted as per the requirements) sequences of double digits
- `$` - end of string (if you only need to match at the beginning of a string, you may remove this anchor).

Comment: It does not match the same strings as the original. It should be `^(?:\d{2}){1,4}N`

Comment: @wdosanjos: I am almost sure `N` stands for some "magic" number that will quantifier the original alternation sequence. Anyway, I added notes to the explanation so that the pattern could be adjusted as per any specific requirements.

Comment: I see how this works for patterned numbers of digits like the one in the example and I am likely accepting this answer for it. Still, is there an approach that can be applied for less consistent discrete amounts of digits? 
Crazy example: number of digits has to be a prime number (of a limited set)? (2,3,5,7,11,13,17)

Comment: If you can't use a limiting quantifier, you will either have to use nested optional groups (less readable version, e.g. [`/^\d{2}(?:\d(?:\d{2}(?:\d{2}(?:\d{4}(?:\d{2}(?:\d{4})?)?)?)?)?)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/L8GsfE/1)) or a verbose [`/^(?:\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{5}|\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{13}|\d{17})$/`](https://regex101.com/r/L8GsfE/3). There is no alternative in the regex world.